# PSD is a different size on another computer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am designing a postcard and the size of my design is 177x122mm, which I obviously saved as a PSD right awa. Here comes the tricky part. When I send this file to another designer and they open it on their computer, in another photoshop, the size is signifiantly different?

I even added grid markings to show me where my bleed was and when they adjust check the size of the canvas on their end, it shows that "my" PSD is completely off? I believe the size they see is something like 150x119mm. I don't exactly know for sure but it's more than just a few digits off the 177x122mm size we're supposed to be working on.

I gave the file in a USB. I really can't think of why it does this but you guys know better, so please help?

Comment: I've *never* seen such a thing happen. If the `Image > Image Size` dialog reads 177x122mm on one system, it should read the same on *any* system. Perhaps someone is "eyeballing" the measurements via the rulers?

Comment: Maybe you're using artboards and they have an ancient Photoshop? Impossible to say without info on both machines and the file.

Comment: @Scott right? That is what I thought too. I have never actually seen anything like this happen before in all my projects except for this one. But I can't say we are. I made the file 177x122mm when I created a new document and haven't changed it since. Hmmm, it suddenly works now but this is after the fifth attempt of us trying to pass the file to one another. So strange.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy How would I see if I am using artboards? Normally my documents look the same... I might be blur to the difference now. But yeah it's strange seeing as how we both have the latest Photoshop and the latest Windows...

Comment: Stupid use error is the most likely cause. I bet they were placing it in their template of some kind.

Comment: I would help to know _exactly_ what size they see, and maybe to get a screenshot of yours and theirs `Image -> Image size ...` panel.